# При записи данных в json сохраняются не все данные

Tags: python, json, requests

Есть сайт
`https://www.houzz.ru/ideabooks/`

Есть код

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
# import time
from random import randrange
import json

def get_first_news():

    url = "https://www.houzz.ru/ideabooks/"

    headers = {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

    r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    for p in range(11, 33, 11):

        url = f"https://www.houzz.ru/ideabooks/p/{p}"
        print(url)


        r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
        sleep(3)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

        all_name_links = soup.find_all(class_="gallery-card hz-browse-galleries-list__gallery")

        news_dict = {}
        for item in all_name_links:
            author_name = item.find("a", class_="gallery-text__author-name").text.strip()
            image_post = item.find("img", class_="gallery-image__responsive")['src']
            dir_post = item.find("div", class_="gallery-text__description text-l").text.strip()
            comment_post = item.find("a", class_="gallery-text__comments").text.strip()
            title_post = item.find("a", class_="gallery-text__title hz-track-me").text.strip()
            link_post = item.find("a", class_="gallery-text__title hz-track-me")["href"]

                # print(f"{author_name}: {image_post}: {dir_post}: {comment_post}: {title_post}: {link_post}")

            news_dict = {
                "author_name": author_name,
                "image_post": image_post,
                "dir_post": dir_post,
                "title_post": title_post,
                "comment_post": comment_post,
                "link_post": link_post
            }
            print(news_dict)

            # with open("news_dict.json", "w") as file:
            #     json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

def main():
    get_first_news()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

При записи в json сохраняется только одна статья. На print выводится все как надо, но в json только одна статья...Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы перезаписываете словарь в файл при каждом проходе цикла. Можно сделать так:

```py
def get_first_news():

    ...

    news_dict = {'news': []}  # создаём словарь перед всеми циклами
    for p in range(11, 33, 11):

        ...

        for item in all_name_links:
            author_name = item.find("a", class_="gallery-text__author-name").text.strip()
            image_post = item.find("img", class_="gallery-image__responsive")['src']
            dir_post = item.find("div", class_="gallery-text__description text-l").text.strip()
            comment_post = item.find("a", class_="gallery-text__comments").text.strip()
            title_post = item.find("a", class_="gallery-text__title hz-track-me").text.strip()
            link_post = item.find("a", class_="gallery-text__title hz-track-me")["href"]

                # print(f"{author_name}: {image_post}: {dir_post}: {comment_post}: {title_post}: {link_post}")

            news_dict['news'].append({  # добавляем в список словарь
                "author_name": author_name,
                "image_post": image_post,
                "dir_post": dir_post,
                "title_post": title_post,
                "comment_post": comment_post,
                "link_post": link_post
            })

    with open("news_dict.json", "w") as file:  # после всех циклов записываем в файл
        json.dump(news_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: в вашем варианте теперь в файл он записывает 11 последних статей. Проходит 8 страниц. На каждой по 11. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Теперь у вас та же проблема, но в другом цикле. Сейчас отредактирую ответ, чтобы показать как это решить.

Comment: @Илья, поправил.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Я тут новенький, теперь я понял.

Answer (score 4):

Как я понял, единственная статья, которая у вас записывается в файл, является последней статьёй из всего списка. Дело в том, что вы в конце каждой итерации цикла открываете файл `news_dict.json` на перезапись. Старые данные удаляются, новые, соответственно, записываются на их место.

Чтобы это избежать, вам следует создать пустой список перед циклом и аккумулировать туда словари `news_dict` (на каждой итерации с использованием метода `append()`). После отработки цикла вы уже сохраняете свой список со словарями в файл, используя ту конструкцию, что у вас закомментирована.

Comment: У меня почти то же самое, но на 7 секунд быстрее )

Comment: Спасибо огромное всем.

Comment: @wchistow В таких случаях, если разрыв репутации между отвечающими большой, то принято отдавать приоритет ответа новичкам, чтобы у них рос рейтинг.

Answer (score 1):

Строка `with open("news_dict.json", "w") as file:` открывает файл `news_dict.json` на перезапись. Как сказано в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open):

> 'w' open for writing, truncating the file first

Но надо задать другой режим функции `open`, поставить `a`. Этот режим работы не перезаписывает весь файл, а дописывает в его конец. Из документации:

> 'a' open for writing, appending to the end of file if it exists

То есть в вашем коде строку:

```py
with open("news_dict.json", "w") as file:
```

надо заменить на:

```py
with open("news_dict.json", "a") as file:
                           # ^
```

Всё очень просто.

Comment: Спасибо. Я пробовал так....в таком виде его отказывается подгружать aiogram.....ругается не открывает. Не нравится ему структура файла..

Comment: В итоге у вас в файле будет записано по словарю на каждую статья, а в JSON-файле должен быть только одна структура данных (словарь, список, ...).